# How to omit the optional function which is parameter

Tags: typescript

I have no problem with optional primitive parameters but with optional function.
Lets say i have function which needs 1 required parameter and one optional

```
function doSomething(value: string, callback?: () => void){
let temp = value;
callback(); // callback!() also doesn't work
}

doSomething('test') // this line throws 'callback is not a function'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do it is to check whether the callback was provided:

```
function doSomething(value: string, callback?: () => void){
    if (callback !== undefined) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

If that makes sense in your case, a default argument can be also used.

```
function doSomething(value: string, callback: () => void = () => {}){
    callback();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use the post bang like:

```
callback!();
```

what you're doing is asserting that, at this point in the interpretation of your code, callback will exist regardless of it being an optional value. So the `typescript` compiler thinks you're doing something like this:

```
doSomething('test', undefined)
```

because you told it that callback would exist.

Instead you should manually check for the value:

```
if(callback){
  callback();
}
```

This should clear up any errors

Answer (score 1):

Try using this syntax:

```
let t = function (a, b = () => { console.log('default') }) {
    b()
} 

t(1);
t(()=>{console.log('passed')})
```

When you use `=` in function param definition, you no longer need `?`

Comment: do not forget to mark correct answer to help other people wandering the same find the solution quickly